# Python warnings filter is not hiding this DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, microstrategy

Even when switching to `mstrio.project_objects.dashboard` it still shows deprecation warning and ignoring it doesn't work

```
$ pip install -Uq mstrio-py
$ export PYTHONWARNINGS='ignore:mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated:DeprecationWarning'
$ python3 -c 'from mstrio.project_objects import dashboard'
DeprecationWarning: mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated and will not be supported starting from mstrio-py 11.5.03. Please use mstrio.project_objects.dashboard instead.
$ python3 -W "ignore:mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated:DeprecationWarning" -c "from mstrio.project_objects import dashboard"
DeprecationWarning: mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated and will not be supported starting from mstrio-py 11.5.03. Please use mstrio.project_objects.dashboard instead.
```

Guarding the import using a context manager doesn't work either

```
>>> import warnings
>>> with warnings.catch_warnings():
...     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=".*mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated.*")
...     from mstrio.project_objects import dashboard
... 
DeprecationWarning: mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated and will not be supported starting from mstrio-py 11.5.03. Please use mstrio.project_objects.dashboard instead.
```

Why doesn't it go away? How to avoid this deprecation warning?

This is latest mstrio-py i.e. [11.4.3.101](https://pypi.org/project/mstrio-py/11.4.3.101/).

Comment: pip install --upgrade mstrio-py :D

Comment: @user70 it is already the latest version

Comment: try to do this in a single line pls `python3 -W "ignore:mstrio.project_objects.dossier module is deprecated:DeprecationWarning" -c "from mstrio.project_objects import dashboard"` does it work?

Comment: @user70 No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`mstrio` [overrides your warning filter](https://github.com/MicroStrategy/mstrio-py/blob/02628a945ca638958de11acd29a105131a54e818/mstrio/config.py#L31-L35):

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action=print_warnings, module=module_path)
warnings.filterwarnings(
    action=print_warnings, category=DeprecationWarning, module=module_path
)
warnings.filterwarnings(action='default', category=UserWarning, module=module_path)
```

It also [monkey-patches the warning formatter](https://github.com/MicroStrategy/mstrio-py/blob/02628a945ca638958de11acd29a105131a54e818/mstrio/config.py#L25-L30), which is why your warning message doesn't look like it normally would:

```
def custom_formatwarning(msg, category, *args, **kwargs):
    # ignore everything except the message
    return str(category.__name__) + ': ' + str(msg) + '\n'


warnings.formatwarning = custom_formatwarning
```

There's a lot of stuff in that file that this package *really* shouldn't be doing. Your best option may be to raise an issue with MicroStrategy and ask them to change this.

Comment: But doesn't this affect everything and not just mstrio own namespace? How to import mstrio without it messing with global state?  Also why is it warning to use `mstrio.project_objects.dashboard` instead, when that is what was already using

Comment: @nosteponsnek: Yes, this affects everything. This package really shouldn't be doing any of this. This code just sucks.

Comment: The warning happens because `mstrio` *itself* [imports](https://github.com/MicroStrategy/mstrio-py/blob/02628a945ca638958de11acd29a105131a54e818/mstrio/project_objects/__init__.py#L10) its own deprecated `mstrio.project_objects.dossier` submodule, triggering its own deprecation warning.

Comment: The only *good* way to avoid any of this behavior is with changes on MicroStrategy's end. For bad ways, you're stuck with options like editing the installed library files yourself, or monkey-patching `__import__` to prevent `mstrio.config` from being loaded.